# Reading a path from a nested grep yields "No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, quoting

Essentially, I have a file containing the path to another file. A single line looks like this.

```
"/home/self/file"
```

Now, separately...

```
> cat "/home/self/file"
blah blah
...

> grep '".*"' /path/to/containing/file
"/home/self/file"

> cat $(grep '".*"' /path/to/containing/file)
cat: "/home/self/file": No such file or directory
```

The results are weird. How do I circumvent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the double quotes.

If possible modify the `path/to/containing/file` and remove the quotes.
If not possible add a piped process (`tr` or `sed` or something similar) to remove the quotes from the process substitution.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's it. Any idea why that is? `cat` doesn't seem to mind quotes ordinarily.

Comment: In your first command, the quotes are processed by the shell before being sent to `cat`, quotes are simply never part of the file name. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solves your issue.